# Parsing date time from mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to convert mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss to more  easly redable form.

Eg:
"12-30-2017 06:10:54" to "12th December 6:10PM" using javascript.

Someone help.

Comment: i really recommend to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for dates

Comment: [MDN: Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript `Date()` object.

Enter the date you want to format into `new Date(date)` where `var date = "12-30-2017 06:10:54"`.

```
new Date("12-30-2017 06:10:54") // Sat Dec 30 2017 06:10:54 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

Note the timezone may vary depending on your device and location.

You could then convert it to a string and split it to show the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way if you really don't want to use `moment.js`

**Parsing this format to the date data type**

```
let dt = '12-30-2017 06:10:54';
dt = dt.split(' ');
let [date, time] = [dt[0].split('-').map(Number), dt[1].split(':').map(Number)];
let d = new Date(date[2], date[0] - 1, date[1], time[0], time[1], time[2], 0);
```

**Convert it into your format**

```
function myDate(date) {
let hh = date.getHours();
let ampm = hh >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
mm = date.getMinutes();
let time = hh + ':' + mm + ampm;
let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
let dd=ordinal_suffix_of(date.getDate());
let month=monthNames[date.getMonth()];
let dt=dd+' '+month;
return dt+' '+time;
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
let dt = '12-30-2017 06:10:54';
dt = dt.split(' ');
let [date, time] = [dt[0].split('-').map(Number), dt[1].split(':').map(Number)];
let d = new Date(date[2], date[0] - 1, date[1], time[0], time[1], time[2], 0);


function myDate(date) {
  let hh = date.getHours();
  let ampm = hh >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  mm = date.getMinutes();
  let time = hh + ':' + mm + ampm;
  let monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  let dd = ordinal_suffix_of(date.getDate());
  let month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  let dt = dd + ' ' + month;
  return dt + ' ' + time;
}

function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
  var j = i % 10,
    k = i % 100;
  if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
    return i + "st";
  }
  if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
    return i + "nd";
  }
  if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
    return i + "rd";
  }
  return i + "th";
}

console.log(myDate(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Momen.js` for converting  Date/Time format (https://momentjs.com/)
1. install `yarn add moment`
2. `import moment from "moment";`

```
console.log(
      "Conversion: ",
      moment(new Date()).format("Do MMMM  h:mm a")
    );
```

output : **30th December  7:37 pm**